# Combine netstat command and geoiplookup

Tags: geolocation, netstat, ip-geolocation

how can I combine the following command:

```
netstat -atun | awk '{print $ 5}' | cut-d: f1 | -e sed '/ ^ $ / d' | sort | uniq-c | sort-n
```

and "geoiplookup" listing something like "Con. Number, IP, Country"

I am using this lib: 
http://kbeezie.com/geoiplookup-command-line/

Thank you for your help! 
best regards

Comment: I think your brute-force keyword is what's causing this to be a negative question. You're just trying to determine which countries your traffic is from correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with something like this:

```
netstat -an -f inet | awk '{print $ 5}' | sed -e '/^\*\.\*$/d' | awk 'sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"")' | uniq | sort -n | xargs -n 1 geoiplookup { } | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed -r 's/ GeoIP Country Edition://g'
```

`netstat -an -f inet` - shows all network related data structures with network addresses as numbers and pulls the inet address family

`awk '{print $ 5}'` - takes that input and presents only the ip address with port from the prior.

`sed -e '/^\*\.\*$/d'` - strips out all of the *.* lines

`awk 'sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"")'` - strips the port number leaving the ip address alone

`uniq` - gets rid of the duplicate ips

`sort -n` - performs a numeric sort (not necessary)

`xargs -n 1 geoiplookup { }` - takes the first input an performs the lookup for the country

`sort` - sorts based on country name

`uniq -c` - groups the country names with a count

`sort -n` - organizes the countries based on the count

`sed -r 's/ GeoIP Country Edition://g'` - Strips the phrasing "GeoIP Country Edition:"

This has little to do with brute force, other than telling you which country the connections are coming from.

Comment: The command is not working correctly for me. 
Have you tested? 

Thanks for the support!

Comment: This is the best version but put ip on new line: netstat -atun | awk '$5 ~ /^[1-9]/ { print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' | sed -e '/127.0.0.1/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{print "Ligacoes: "$1" IP:"$2" - Pais:"; $pais=system("geoiplookup "$2)}'

Comment: I tested it on MacOS but didn't load it into any of my other boxes. Yeah I was wondering why you weren't keeping the IP?